# why i am getting page not found error in netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, netlify

I used netlify's Drag and Drop functionality to host my React App , But I got page not found error
and also I created `netlify.toml` file and there corresponding codes i wrote like this

```js
 command = "npm run build"
  publish = "/build"
  base "/"


[[redirects]]
from = "/*"
to = "/index.html"
status = 200
```

but I am still getting this error.

> Page Not Found
>
> Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site.
>
> Back to our site
>
> If this is your site, and you weren't expecting a 404 for this path, please visit Netlify's "page not found" support guide for troubleshooting tips.

This is my app link

https://silly-crostata-1ed9b8.netlify.app